# How can I hide ldapbindpasswd in PostgreSQL LDAP authentication?

Tags: postgresql, authentication, ldap

I've added the following to `pg_hba.conf` and LDAP authentication works.

```
host all all 0.0.0.0/0  ldap ldapserver=ldap.p***ad.com ldapbasedn="ou=US,ou=NA,dc=p***ad,dc=com" ldapbinddn="cn=LOEM,OU=Some Accounts,OU=Enterprise Mgmt,OU=NA,dc=p***ad,dc=com" ldapbindpasswd="*****" ldapsearchattribute=sAMAccountName
```

But I do not want to leave the password in plain text.  Is there way not to include `ldapbindpasswd` in `pg_hba.conf`?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that.

I would suggest that you configure the LDAP server for anonymous bind to search this information, then you don't need a password.

Comment: In case anonymous access isn't allowed: is it possible to reuse the client supplied credentials for ldapbasedn and ldapbindpasswd? Tried ldapbasedn="$username" and ldapbindpasswd="$password" but that doesn't work.

Comment: I don't think that is an option.

Comment: You are right, checked the source code and it's only using it for the filter